# Calculating constant current buck converter ripple current

Tags: buck, led-driver, constant-current

For building a constant current LED driver, I'm looking at the TI LM3407 datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3407.pdf

For calculating the necessary inductor, there's several things I don't understand:

- Under `8.1.4 Selection of Inductor` The datasheet lists ripple current as
  \$
  I_{L(ripple)} = \frac{\left(V_{IN} - V_{OUT} - 0.198 \times \left(1 + \frac 1 R_{ISNS}\right)\right) \times V_{OUT}}{L\times V_{IN} \times f_{SW}}
  \$

What I don't understand is where the term with the sense resistor is coming from,  my understanding of a buck converter is that it depends only on duty cycle, frequency and inductance, but not output current?
**Edit:** I guess that's the on resistance of the built in MOSFET - which is given as 0.77 Ohm typical, 1.45 Ohm max (at 80mA).

- On the next page, there's `Table 1. Suggested Inductance Value of the Inductor`, which e.g. lists 22µH for driving 5 LEDs with 1MHz from 25V, with \$I_{L(ripple)} = 0.8 \times I_{OUT}\$. But inserting those values into above formula, I arrive at >250mA ripple current, indpendent of \$I_{OUT}\$.
  E.g. with \$I_{OUT} = 100mA, R_{ISNS} = 2\Omega\$, that ripple current seems excessive?
- The datasheet has some suggested output capacitor sizes, but no information at all for how output capacitor size relates to LED ripple current. What's a good resource to learn about this?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: I'm relatively new to the field, so no idea how I would do that.

Comment: I don't see precisely that formula in the data sheet 8.1.4

Comment: It has number of LEDs times forward voltage in there instead of Vout.

Comment: A great time to learn! Download LTspice (it’s free) and draw your circuit. We’ll help you from there. You can of course derive a formula for it, but if your end goal is a real circuit and not a theoretical exercise, you probable reach your goals quicker with simulations.

Comment: I've assembled a crude simulation of the LM3407 in LTspice (i.e. pulse voltage source hand tuned for the resulting current + mosfet). It seems to confirm that ripple current is mostly independent of the set current, so I guess the table is really just for high current values (there it seems to make sense) - i.e. R_isns <= 1Ohm.